# How to extend the Swift Dictionary type to return a non-empty String or nil

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, foundation

I'm writing an `extension` to `Dictionary` so that when I give it a `String` key, it'll return me a `String` only if the value associated with the key is **non-nil and not empty**.

```
extension Dictionary {

    subscript(key: String) -> String? {
        if let string = super.subscript(key) {
            if string.isEmpty == false {
                return string
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

However, at the `if let string = super.subscript(key) {` line, I get the following compile error and I don't know what it means--neither is there a Google result that explains it:

> Expected `->` for subscript element type

I am doing this because I'm working with an API that returns a JSON where a key's value may be an empty string--which is an invalid value to the app by our requirements, and hence, as good as nil.

Of course the longer way works, but I'm looking for a way to make this shorter.

```
if let value = dict["key"] as? String {
    if value.isEmpty == false {
        // The value is non-nil and non-empty.
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Instead, do `if let value = dictionary["key"] as? String where !value.isEmpty { ... }`

Comment: @mattt Sounds good, make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Apple has an interesting article on a possibly related topic: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=12

Comment: Btw, one technical problem here is that you assume that the dictionary keys are strings, which need not be the case. And you cannot define an extension method that applies to a restricted type of the generic placeholder only.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @MartinR. Guess I'm going mattt's way then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to think this is very silly, but my suggestion would be: do more or less exactly what you're doing, but encapsulate it as a separate function rather than trying to deal with the implications of defining a new `subscript`:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func nes(key:Key) -> String? {
        var result : String? = nil
        if let s = self[key] as? String {
            if !s.isEmpty {
                result = s
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

(`nes` stands for "non-empty string".)

Now call it like `d.nes("foo")`.

Comment: I already resorted to writing a global function that does the same thing, but I still don't think this is silly!

Comment: Actually the global function was going to be my first suggestion! :))) But then I said to myself, no, let's save ourselves one parameter.